# How do stocks work? (Cryptocurrency analogy)

Tags: stocks, cryptocurrency

I come from a cryptocurrency background (Bitcoin etc.). I have no idea how stocks work and how to invest into stocks.

In cryptocurrencies for example, I am in full control my assets (private key) and can view my assets on public directories (block explorers). I purchase cryptocurrencies through exchanges and can withdraw them to my own wallet. To me, this is simple and straight forward.

Can someone please explain how stocks works with blockchain analogies?
Where can I buy stocks? Are there exchanges for that? Can I purchase stocks through my bank? Where can I store my stocks? What happens if my bank goes bankrupt? Are my stocks gone when my bank goes bankrupt? Can I transfer stocks to another place? Where can I see how much stock I own? Can I print out something like a proof of ownership? Is there something like a block explorer for stocks? Can I give a stock to a friend or family member as a gift? Can own a fraction of a stock? (Like 1/100 of Berkshire Hathaway). Are my stocks accessible to me when I move to another country? What about ETFs?

As you can see, I have absolutely no clue how stocks work. This might seem odd, but I guess the future generations will have similar questions. Thank you.

Comment: Cryptocurrencies operate much more like stock than you seem to realize. Ignoring the fact that the *idea* of cryptocurrencies are to replace "normal" currencies, they behave almost exactly like stock: you own part of a limited asset, backed by an algorithmically induced scarcity rather than the assets of a company.

Comment: For example, you buy and sell cryptocurrencies on an exchange because that's how things like stock have been bought and sold for centuries.

Comment: "I am in full control my assets" until a hacker steals it, or you forget the key.

Comment: "Stock" is fractional ownership in a company, which underlies the @DStanley answer.

Comment: The main difference between Bitcoin and stock ownership is that stock ownership is not a scam vehicle for money launderers to transfer their wealth by convincing speculators that a fake asset is actually real.

Comment: @chepner: But stocks differ from cryptocurrencies in a very fundamental way.  Stocks represent ownership of part of a company, which generally has assets, makes & sells products, and eventually distributes those profits to shareholders, thus the stock has some inherent value.  The value of a cryptocurrency depends only on convinving other people that they want it.

Comment: @jamesqf The question seems focused on the mechanics of buying and selling stock, not the benefits of owning stock. From that perspective, both are just assets you can buy, hold, then sell, hopefully at a profit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can someone please explain how stocks works with blockchain analogies?

Well, that's a little like explaining football using a potato as an analogy since there are many fundamental differences, but I'll answer your specific questions.

> Where can I buy stocks? Are there exchanges for that?

Set up an account with a broker which can buy/sell stocks for you through a stock exchange. Individuals do not buy stocks directly through the exchange

> Can I purchase stocks through my bank?

No. Some "banks" will have an investment bank arm that can serve as a broker, but the bank itself (in the purest sense of the term) cannot act as a broker.

> Where can I store my stocks?

You *can* get physical stock certificates, but nowadays they just sit with your broker in electronic records.

> What happens if my bank goes bankrupt?  Are my stocks gone when my bank goes bankrupt?

Given the above answer I'm going to change "bank" to "broker". The broker is just an intermediary. They do not own the stocks - YOU do. If a broker goes bankrupt someone will buy (or be given by a judge) the rights to ast as your new broker and will get all of your electronic records.

> Can I transfer stocks to another place?

If by "place" you mean broker, then sure. Most large brokers have standard processes for transferring securities in or out.

> Where can I see how much stock I own?

From your broker's website - they must also send you (either physically or electronically) quarterly statements showing you your holdings and transactions.

> Can I print out something like a proof of ownership?

Not sure what you mean by this - like I said above you *can* get physical certificates but your electronic records will probably suffice.

> Is there something like a block explorer for stocks?

No.

> Can I give a stock to a friend or family member as a gift?

Yes but it's not as easy as (I presume from the question) giving cryptocurrency. There are more rules and regulations about transferring ownership of stocks since, for example, the ownership must be conveyed to the service that distributed dividend payments (among other things).

> Can own a fraction of a stock?

In limited cases, yes. Some brokers support selling fractional shares, but in those cases you don't really *own* the share - you have a *record* with the broker that indicates that you have the right to a fraction of a share. But it usually only happens in the case of splits or if you have a broker that supports low-volume trades.

Note that fractions are MUCH LESS common in equities that in crypto.

> Are my stocks accessible to me when I move to another country?

Same as your bank account.

> What about ETFs?

A Mutual Fund is a fund that owns many stocks and sells you "units" that are much more common as fractions. They are a way to diversify without having to buy many different stocks yourself.  An ETF is just a mutual fund that trades during the day (Mutual Funds have existed long before computers and couldn't practically trade during the day - only at the end of the day when they could aggregate the value of all of their holdings).

> As you can see, I have absolutely no clue how stocks work.

There are many more fundamental differences that you didn't hit on - dividends, voting rights, how to *value* a stock (which is completely different that the speculative crypto market), etc.

Comment: Might also add a bit about mutual funds, since they're a much more convenient way of owning stocks (and bonds &c) than purchasing individual stocks.  And they easily solve the fractional share ownership question.

Comment: Wrt proof of ownership: when buying stock the broker/bank sends a bill/receipt. This is proof of ownership just like the receipt from the bike store is proof of ownership for my bike. In addition, the broker regularly sends an account statement which details which shares/bonds/... I have in my account with them.

Comment: @jamesqf More than what's in the next to last paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

> I come from a cryptocurrency background (Bitcoin etc.)

I come from an automotive background, so I'm the perfect person to explain stocks to you.  You laugh, but it really is like that. **Your experience playing with "Hacker ForEx" is inapplicable**.

> I have no idea how stocks work and how to invest into stocks.

Good on you. Your first task is to read John Bogle's **Common sense on mutual funds**.  It's the story of a very talented stock picker and his very expensive research staff, and a monkey, and a major index (list) of stocks. And who does the best.

> In cryptocurrencies for example, I am in full control my assets (private key) and can view my assets on public directories (block explorers). I purchase cryptocurrencies through exchanges and can withdraw them to my own wallet. To me, this is simple and straight forward.

I find just doing a walkaround, stepping into a car, turning the ignition and pushing the clutch to select a gear "simple and straightforward". But I don't expect Bitcoin to work like that, do I?  So I don't believe you should hold an expectation that "all money-like things should work like I'm used to".

> Where can I buy stocks? Are there exchanges for that? Can I purchase stocks through my bank? 
>   Where can I see how much stock I own?

The line is blurring between "banks" and **brokerage houses**: In the modern age many banks have brokerages and many brokerages have banks, For instance my broker has had a Single-Sign-On with my bank for 20 years, even though they were technically separate companies.

It's as easy as this:  You sign up for a Vanguard account.  Part of this will be a rigmarole of ID-checking, caused by the US "Know Your Customer" laws. (which is designed to prevent criminal use of the banking system; *note that the Bitcoin system has none of this*).

Then, you transfer $500 into the Vanguard account, either via EFT, or mailing a paper cheque.  One thing that will astonish you is how certain cryptographic interlocks *could* exist that *do not*, at least just a little application of PKE.  The security is largely via Know-Your-Customer and the ability to clawback wrong payments.   *Again, clawback is not a Bitcoin concept*.

Then, you log into Vanguard and say "Buy...", pick a stock or ETF (let's say VTI), pick number of shares or dollar value, optionally pick a few minor criteria like when and at what price or wait for a price to happen, then hit "OK" and confirm.  Boom, you own the stock.

- You can then sell it with the "Sell" function.
- You can "buy" on margin; say you deposited $500 but buy $1000 of the stock. You're borrowing the other $500. This amplifies volatility, and may be subject to a "margin call".
- You can also buy an "Option to buy": say pay $42 now, *for the right* to pay $31 for 100 shares of XYZ later.  The $42 is forfeit, but if XYZ falls to $19, you simply throw away the option. If it rises to $35, you make a quick $400 profit, *or simply sell the option*.
- You can do "Puts" the same deal, but advantaging you if the stock goes down.
- It gets way crazier than that.  Note that these are all things Bogle's book tells you not to do.

Bitcoin is more akin to ForEx, or trading in foreign currencies. But not that much like it, because even ForEx relies on relationships with certified brokers, who are well-regulated, and subject to prosecution. The level of slop that happens in the Bitcoin world (e.g. [Mt Gox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt._Gox), WTH??) would *be a Federal crime* if it was done in stocks or ForEx.  **Markets are a nice, safe place to lose all your money!**

> Can own a fraction of a stock? (Like 1/100 of Berkshire Hathaway).

Whether you need to buy integer stock units varies by the stock or fund's policy.  If they want small investors, they will either allow fractional shares  (e.g. mutual funds), or price individual shares in digestable nuggets, such as VTI's $168.76, which will allow a $500 investor to buy 3 shares.

This, for instance, is why [Apple did a 7:1 split](https://www.forbes.com/sites/chuckjones/2019/12/27/apple-stock-broke-2000-pre-split/) some years ago.  At $655/share it didn't appeal to investors because it wasn't granular enough.

This is also how exclusive stocks, like Berkshire Hathaway, "keep out the riff-raff".   However, [accessible ETFs](https://etfdb.com/stock/BRK.B/) own Berkshire Hathaway, with as much as 15% of their holdings.

> Where can I store my stocks? 
>   What happens if my bank goes bankrupt?
>   Are my stocks gone when my bank goes bankrupt?

It's in trust at the brokerage.  "Trust" is a word that will keep coming up here; it basically means if you cheat anyone, you get a years-long sabbatical at Club Fed, which is for low-violence-risk low-escape-risk prisoners like financiers.

Trust means it's your stock, and the brokerage's job is to manage it for  you, **and they cannot touch your stocks or your cash to buy copier paper**.  If they do, they're in Club Fed.  *More concepts alien to the Bitcoin world*.

Further, there is **insurance** for certain classes of assets.  For instance if they somehow "lose your stock", but more relevantly, any cash in the account is probably [FDIC insured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Deposit_Insurance_Corporation).  *I don't recall any World Bitcoin Insurance Corp. covering everyone's losses after Mt. Gox; if that existed, Mt. Gox would have been required (by the insurer) to have much, much better [controls](https://simplicable.com/new/financial-controls). This is the trouble with Bitcoin; everybody saw how well the US mainstream financial system is run, and arrogantly thought "Well, if those dinosaurs can do it, it must be easy!"*

What actually happens in bankruptcy is the "assets get liquidated", and **the customer relationships, accounts and portfolios-in-trust** are the #1 asset.  So another brokerage purchases (at fire-sale prices) the core business, employees, computers and all.  You see a different name on the website banner.  "Stocks-R-Us *by Fidelity*".  Then over the next 2 years, there's an employee bloodletting, as the acquirer cherry-picks the best staff and business systems between the two companies.  This can be part of a bankruptcy scramble as other brokers vie for those employees and business systems.

**Direct** ownership of stock is also possible.  But it's very expensive, complex and burdensome for publicly traded companies.  The brokerage system saves them a fortune in overhead costs.  So **companies will do whatever it takes to protect your confidence in that system**. And they're the ones who issue the stock!

> Can I transfer stocks to another place?  Can I print out something like a proof of ownership?  Can I give a stock to a friend or family member as a gift?  Are my stocks accessible to me when I move to another country? What about ETFs?

Yes, stocks can be moved **as stocks**. This is done for a reason: taxes.  There is a concept called "tax basis", or the price you paid for the stock.  When someone sells a stock, they are taxed only on the gains beyond *tax basis*. Further the amount of time holding a stock decides whether it's taxed as a short-term gain (i.e. speculation/flipping) or a long-term gain (investing in the nation's industry). That means an unnecessary sell/re-buy *is a bad thing*, which is why they facilitate transferring stocks *as* stocks.  ETFs act like stocks.

The recipient would need a brokerage account of their own.

For instance, suppose I paid $1000 for a stock.  It has grown to $5000 and I donate it to Charity.  I could sell it and donate $5000 cash, pay capital gains tax on $4000 and take the $5000 tax deduction. Or, I could donate *the stock*, pay $0 capital gains *since I didn't sell it*, take the $5000 tax deduction based on current value.  Much better!  The charity's cost basis is $0, so have $5000 of capital gains; that's taxed for them at 0% rate.

> Is there something like a block explorer for stocks?

I don't know what that is, but there is stupid amounts of data about stocks, and lots of people analyzing it. You could spend a whole lifetime doing stock data analysis, and not come up with anything truly new.